# Unity 2D: Extend a LineRenderer Line to the edge of the screen based on mouse position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity 2D: I have a working function below that detects the position of the mouse and draws a line with the LineRenderer from a fixed game object sprite to the mouse position.

What I want to do is have the line extend past the mouse position to the edge of the screen (or beyond it). I can't figure out how, though. Any ideas?

Thank you!

```
public class LineToMouse : MonoBehaviour
{

    Vector3 startPos;
    Vector3 mousePos;

    Camera cam;
    LineRenderer lr;

    void Start()
    {
        lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Get starting line position
        startPos = gameObject.transform.position;
        startPos.z = 0;

        // Set the line renderer start point
        lr.SetPosition(0, startPos);

        // Get the current mouse position
        mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mousePos.z = 0;

        // Set the line renderer end point
        lr.SetPosition(1, mousePos);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't matter that it ends exactly with the screen border you could simply extend it by the size of the screen like e.g.

```
var startPosScreen = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(startPos);
var mousePosScreen = Input.mousePosition;
var direction = (mousePosScreen - startPosScreen).normalized;
var targetPosScreen = startPosScreen + direction * Mathf.Max(Screen.width, Screen.height);
var mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(targetPosScreen);
mousePos.z = 0;
```

---

Otherwise if you need it to be exactly the screen border see the duplicate link I just found again.

Comment: Thank you for this! Works great. Also, I think the previous question you linked to is interesting, but a slightly different question (and more complicated answer) than mine -- to this Unity beginner, anyway. Appreciate your help!